# Error with spark-cassandra-connector in Spark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/ProtocolOptions$Compression

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have this error when I try to connect to cassandra with spark-cassandra-connector:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/ProtocolOptions$Compression
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.(CassandraConnectorConf.scala:112)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.(CassandraConnectorConf.scala)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:192)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.SparkContextFunctions.cassandraTable$default$3(SparkContextFunctions.scala:48)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark$.main(TestSpark.scala:19)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark.main(TestSpark.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolOptions$Compression
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 15 more
>   I have added the jar in the spark class path
>   spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-1.5.0-M2.jar

I have added the dependencies in the sbt file:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-M2"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.5.0-M2"
```

This is the scala program I try to execute:

```
package main.scala


import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

/**
 * Created by Simo on 01.12.15.
 */
object TestSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "54.229.218.236")
        .setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc= new SparkContext("local", "test", conf)
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
    println(rdd.count)
    println(rdd.first)
    println(rdd.map(_.getInt("value")).sum)
  }
}
```

And this is how i run it:

```
$ sbt package
$ $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "main.scala.TestSpark" target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I have tried to add the Datastax driver in the dependencies list and in the spark classpath:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.9"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-mapping" % "2.1.9"
```

The last error no longer appear but now I have another error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:241)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:51)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:146)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:143)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark$.main(TestSpark.scala:20)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark.main(TestSpark.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Edit 2: Make scala 2.10.6 at compile time (same as the scala version of spark)
The previous error no longer appear but i have this new error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:36)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:85)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:241)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:51)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:150)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:143)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark$.main(TestSpark.scala:20)
>       at main.scala.TestSpark.main(TestSpark.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 34 more

Comment: You could try [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to build include-all JAR or upload datastax libs from ivy cache to spark classpath

Comment: Have you tried to add the spark-cassandra jar to to `spark-submit`? Something like `spark-submit --jars x.jar` with a fat jar whose name is possibly something like `spark-cassandra-connector-xxx.jar`?

Comment: Yes i tried but i have another error (see update question)

Comment: @Odomontois thanks works with your solutions

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved using sbt-assembly as suggested by @Odomontois

This is the final build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.9"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.5.0-M2"



jarName in assembly :="my-project-assembly.jar"

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in             assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)


resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case PathList("netty", "handler", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("netty", "buffer", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("netty", "common", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("netty", "transport", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("netty", "codec", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first

        case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
        case x => old(x)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude, thanks so much.  Any reason why the weird netty errors?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the dependency of Datastax Cassandra Driver from (As per the version of Spark-cassandra connector): -
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/

Comment: I'm added the dependencies in the dependencies list in the sbt file and in the spark class path. Now the last error no longer appear but i have another error. Could you please look at the edit section of the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like scala jars used at compile and runtime are not same. Ensure that you us Scala 2.10.x and remove any other scala versions from classpath,

Comment: Yes i changed the scala version to 2.10.6 but i have another error (see edit 2)

Comment: Thanks it seems to be resolved using sbt-assembly plugin